# Adaptive (multibitrate) streaming for Android

Tags: android, video, streaming

Is it possible to perform adaptive (multibitrate) streaming onto an Android device? If yes, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 4.0 or 3.2 you just use access the adaptive stream as you would any other video. Literally.

It's a HTTP access.

So if you use as a data source //mywebsite/video1.mp4 you woulduse as a data source the equivalent //mywebsite/video1.m3u8.  Now, I'm not including any discussion on how you create your streaming file but only how you would access it.

All the magic happens within the client (ex: mediaplayer, videoview) supported on 4.0 and 3.2.  For the record, you may be able to access and run streaming segments (.m3u8 files) on earlier versions of Android because the manufactures have sometimes played around with the code.  But I haven't found any that actually adapt.  They usually stick to the first segment they run or default to the lower bitrate segment in the bunch and stay there regardless of bitrate.